# Microsoft зарабатывает на андроиде

Tags: android, windowsphone

Есть информация о том, что Майкрософт зарабатывает на Андроиде больше чем на WP. Связано это с тем, что в Андроиде используются технологии Майкрософт, и им(Майкрософту) идёт доля от каждого проданого смартфона. Если это правда, тогда что это за технологии?

**Какие технологии, разработанные, и принадлежащие Microsoft используются в Android устройствах?**

*Для тех кто не понял весьма сложный вопрос, кому он показался обширным:*

**Статьи:**

http://hitech.vesti.ru/news/view/id/3311

http://chezasite.com/android/microsoft-zarabatyvaet-na-andro-31070.html

**ВОПРОС:**

**Перечислите, пожалуйста технологии использующиеся в ПО ОС ANDROID(https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android )(в частности HTC, например), которые являются интелектуальной собственностью корпорации Microsoft(https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft)**